# Type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeahead

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

this is the component ContTypeAhead:

```
 <Typeahead
      id={this.props.name}
      name={this.props.name}
      onChange={this.changeHandler}
      onBlur={this.onBlurHandler}
      onInputChange={this.inputChangeHandler}
      options={this.state.typeAheadOptions}
      placeholder={'Type for ' + this.props.label}
      selected={this.state.selected}
    />
```

Using above component in another component and code is:

```
    <ContTypeAhead
      label="Autex"
      name="autex"
      id="autex"
      size="6"
      options={[]}
      url="settlements/getAutex"
      selected={this.state.autex}
      changed={this.autexChangedHandler}
      wrongSelectionHandler={this.wrongTypeAheadSelectionHandler}
      rightSelectionHandler={this.rightTypeAheadSelectionHandler}
    />;
```

Using TypeScript with CRA. Defined Props and State interface with every field as :any;

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare Your `ContTypeAhead` as a
function.
`const ContTypeAhead = props => {`.
Or.
Class.
`class ContTypeAhead extends Component {`.

Or you dont `return(<ContTypeAhead />)`

Comment: Actually Both things are there, and even I have installed the @types/... . still the issue is persisting.

Comment: Oh..can you include the full code for ContTypeAhead?

Answer (score 0):

This is really annoying issues, but I resolved it. The reason behind the error was that, 
`Typeahead...`, so we have to first of all include `@types` with latest version of Typeahead. Clearly check the keys used, because "name" in not a part of Typeahead in new version. Same like as Calendar. So caused the issue. Removing those solved the issue.

Thanks!